# Copying image from word document seems to be lossy

Tags: microsoft-word, images, microsoft-word-2010

I had setup word to not compress image sizes in a document.

In that way I can keep a number of screenshots for later use in it.

However, when I select an image in a document and copies it, pasting it into gimp will not give me the original amount of pixels of the image.

Why? How to fix?

Right clicking the image in word and "save as picture" will produce an image file with the original amount of pixels, but that would be a hassle.

Comment: "Why?" Because the rendered image is not (usually) the same as the source image. It can be resized and also have a different aspect ratio ...

Comment: I have not experienced any aspect ratio changes. The problem is that I lose all detail.

Comment: I am reading about the problem at https://www.pcworld.com/article/3153419/software/why-extracting-images-from-word-is-so-hard-with-3-decent-workarounds.html at the moment. Seems to not be possible to just copy an image from a word document, using the clipboard with the original amount of detail.

Comment: Whether the aspect ratio is changed or not the image is often resized when it is displayed ...

Comment: You could probably write a macro to copy the original image ...

Comment: [Extract images from a Word document](http://www.gmayor.com/extract_images_from_word.htm)

Comment: I wrote a macro as you suggested that does `Selection.Copy`. That was lossy. The same with `Selection.CopyAsPicture`.

Comment: Have you tried to right click on the image and select save as image, then _open_ the image in GIMP?

Comment: Sorry, I was not clear about being able to do that. Like, I said, right clicking the image in word and "save as picture" will produce an image file with the original amount of pixels.

Answer (score 3):

#### Copying image from word document seems to be lossy

> **How To Extract Embedded Images from a Word Document**
>
> Word documents containing embedded images can not be easily extracted.
>   Attempts to copy and paste the images result in poor quality images or
>   the document contains too many images to copy them individually.   To
>   extract embedded images from a Word document save the document as a
>   web page using the following steps:
>
> 1. On the File menu click Save as Web Page
> 2. In the Save As drop down select Web Page (*.htm; *.html)   Images will be extracted from the document and placed in the folder named
>      `<DocumentName>_files` in the same location as the saved web page.

Source [WD: How To Extract Embedded Images from a Word Document](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/555171)

Answer (score 1):

Make a copy of the file, change the extention to .zip and unzip it. You will get a bunch of XML files and directories. Find one called `media`, the images should be in it.

One downside to this method is that they won't have any descriptive name, only being sequentially numbered.

Comment: I really need to just copy and paste.